# Display contents of a file in grid view

Tags: mysql, asp.net, gridview

I want to display my large sized file in a grid view. I have stored it's link in grid. What my code does is display the path but not the file present at that path.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns = "False"
   Font-Names = "Arial" >

   <Columns>
   <asp:BoundField DataField = "ID" HeaderText = "ID" />
   <asp:BoundField DataField = "FileName" HeaderText = "File Name" />
  <asp:BoundField DataField = "FilePath" HeaderText = "File Path" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a hyperlinkfield something like:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField DataNavigateUrlFields="FilePath,FileName"
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}/{1}" 
    target="_blank" />
```

That will be rendered as a hyperlink for your file for any given path you pass

Comment: @user2444546 - does the link render? Here's an example in msdn: [HyperLinkField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3)

Comment: I do not want to navigate away to another page. I want my file's contents to be displayed here in grid. I tried using Label in <Item template> tags, but it didn't work. I am attaching the screen shot in edit.

Comment: @user2444546 I can't see teh screenshot